# django admin inlines reordering read only fields

Tags: django-admin

I am using tabular inlines in the django admin and have specified two fields to be read only.  However django has now moved these to the very end of the inline (on the far right)  There are a large number of fields, how can I move these 2 fields back to their original position (2nd, 3rd after pk) without having to specify the order of every field with `fields=`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `get_fields()` method of the `ModelAdmin` class:

```
@admin.register(Vintner)
class VintnerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ['field1', 'field2']

    def get_fields(self, request, obj=None):    
        fields = super().get_fields(request, obj)
        fields = fields[-2:] + fields[:-2] # or something more robust              
        return fields
```